# When I move a vertex, it seems like I'm "breaking through" the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I'm trying to make a car from blueprints using a cube and a plane, but
when I move some of my vertex, it seems like I'm "breaking through" the mesh.

It seems like there is some part of the mesh on top which is totally in mobile.
I have tried to put new vertex on the surface, but nothing seems to help.

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong, and how to either prevent it or to repare it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is with your mirror modifier. You're using the *Mirror Modifier* to mirror the car's left side to the right side (or vice versa), but since you've dragged some of the edges/vertices across that mirror line, the mirror modifier is duplicating that, creating overlapping surfaces.

Disable the *Mirror modifier* visibility to see exactly what it's replicating. You'd want to drag all the vertices that cross over the mirror line back. Another way to avoid this type of issue is to enable *Clipping* in the modifier settings (bottom right of your screenshots). This prevents you from dragging any points across the mirror axis, and will *clip* any points to that axis.

Comment: Thanks alot - this work. Im very happy, beccause i was totally mystefied.  regards Frank

Comment: No problem! :-)